# Topology a first course, exercise 2 from section 3.2

Tags: general-topology

Let n be a positive integer. Given that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined by $f(x)= x^n$ is continuous, show that for each $ a\geq0 $ there is exactly one $ b\geq0 $ such that $ b^n=a$.

I thought in to do for contradiction but I'm using only algebra: let $b<c$ such that $b^n=a$ and $c^n=a$, but if $0<b<c$ implies $b^n<c^n$ so we can't have $b^n=a$ and $c^n=a$, contradiction. But I not get an idea to prove this using connected sets in the real line or intermediate value theorem.

Comment: They take the continuity of $f$ as given and want to show that $x^n=a$ has a solution for all $a\geq0$. That sounds like a setup to use the intermediate value theorem. So, all one needs to do is show that there are $x_0,x_1\geq0$ such that $x_0^n<a$ and $x_1^n>a$. This can be done in many ways. One way can be to exploit [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$ to get that if $x_1$ is an integer greater than $(\max(a,2)-1)/n$, then $1+nx_1>a$ and therefore $x_1^n>a$. Similarly, find $x_0$ in the form $1/m$ such that $1/a<m^n$.

Comment: Note that the use of Bernoulli's inequality is only to pass from the exponential function to just a lineal polynomial, for which solving inequalities is simpler. This can be done in any other way you like that produces at least one solution of $x^n>a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\lim_{x \to \infty} = \infty$, exists $d$ with $a < f(d)$.
Also $f(0) \leq a$.  Now apply IVT.
To show $f$ is strictly increasing, prove $f'$ is positive except at $0$.

Topological proof:
$A = f[[0,\infty)] = [0,\infty)$ is connected.
If $a$ not in $A$, then $A$ is disconnected,
Thus $a$ in $A$, exists $b$ with $f(b) = a$.

Exercise: What happens if the domain of $f$ is $Q$?